# Sitecore Federated Authentication on CD server

Tags: sxa, content-delivery, federated-authentication

Using SXA 1.6  and Sitecore 9.01 I manage to enable Federated Authentication on CM so content editors can be authenticated using their Azure AD account using the guide from 
http://sitecore.badalkotecha.com/2017/11/federated-authentication-for-sitecore-9-integrating-with-azuread.html

I would like to do the same but for website visitor to login using their AD account, I add below code in one of my render

```
<div class="external-signin">

                  <a class="btn btn-default btn-block xp0.sc.azureAD" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ExternalSignIn$ctl00$ctl00", "", false, "", "/identity/externallogin?authenticationType=xp0.sc.azureAD&amp;ReturnUrl=%252fidentity%252fexternallogincallback%253fReturnUrl%253d%2526sc_site%253dshell%2526authenticationSource%253dDefault&amp;sc_site=shell", false, true))'><div class="sc-icon" style="background-image: url(/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/Images/24x24/msazure.png)"></div>
                      <span class="external-signin-caption">
                          Sign-in with Azure Active Directory
                      </span>
                  </a>

        </div>
```

I get this issue

```
VM1085:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions is not defined
at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Is there anther way to achieve this?

Comment: is it treated as normal MVC site that integrated with Azure AD ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have properly configured the provider to handle your website authentication. Check `<sites hint="list">`.

You can get login URLs for your site through `GetSignInUrlInfoPipeline` pipeline. Do something like:

```
var corePipelineManager = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<BaseCorePipelineManager>();
var args = new GetSignInUrlInfoArgs("website", url);
GetSignInUrlInfoPipeline.Run(corePipelineManager, args);
```

`args.Result` will have a list of the providers URLs available.

You need to do a `POST` request to these URLs. e.g

```
@foreach (var result in args.Result)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @action = result.Href }))
    {
        <button type="submit">
            <img src="@result.Icon" />
            @result.Caption
        </button>
    }
}
```